# When I run a debug on my program in Visual Studio, the user interface gets cut off. How do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio

Although the [user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weZAp.png)  looks completely fine when I'm building it...

When I launch the program, the right and bottom parts of the [user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzz88.png) get chopped up.

Even if I put the program into full screen, the same thing happens.

I really hope someone can help me with this soon, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a nice feature of the default Winforms project template, you get to see what your app looks like on another machine that doesn't have as big a monitor as yours.  You can ignore it for a while longer by declaring your app to be dpiAware so it doesn't rescale on your dev machine.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time asking a question, and I was glad that I was able to receive help so quickly.